# CSS Modules <style module> doesnt work

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, css-modules

I have Laravel 5.4 project with Vue.js. I wont to use [CSS Modules feature](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/css-modules.html) that provides by vue-loader. I have vue.js file with code:

```
 <template lang="pug">

    .LAYOUT
        .SIDE-NAVBAR
        .MAIN

</template>
<style module>

    .LAYOUT{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

</style>
<script>
    export default {


    methods:{
        test(){
            console.log(this.$style.LAYOUT)
        }
    },

    mounted(){
        this.test();
    }

    }
</script>
```

When I'm trying to see some information about "this.$style.LAYOUT" in console, it shows that the variable is undefined. May be I should do some settings? How to fix it?

When I'm trying to get value of "this.$style", it returns object:
[image]

Comment: You need a closing `</script>` tag.

Comment: @thanksd I have it in my original code. I corrected it here, thank you.

Comment: Then your code works (I tested on my machine). You're sure you're getting `undefined`? What do you get when you log just `this.$style`?

Comment: @thanksd When I'm trying to get value "this.$style.LAYOUT" I get "undefined", I'm sure. When I'm trying to get value "this.$style" I get object.

Comment: What's in the object?

Comment: @thanksd Object is empty. I added picture to the question.

Comment: I'm assuming you have simplified your code to try to show the basic example of the issue. But you must have taken out the problematic code from your example, because when I use this exact code in my own app it works fine.

Comment: @thanksd Ohh. Strange situation. This time I stopped on my first steps. I mean there was nothing to simplify, I got an error and decided to find solution. Goggle didn't give me any answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be undefined because you not using that class.

**Below is a working example.It also includes how to set dynamic css module class:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button :class="[className1, className2, dynamicClass]" @click="showStyleObject">Click Me</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'example',
        props: {
          'type-of-button': {
              validator: function (value) {
                  return ['primary', 'secondary', 'default'].indexOf(value) !== -1
              }
          }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                className1: this.$style.button,
                className2: this.$style.button2,
            }
        },
        created() {
            console.log(this.$style.button)
            console.log(this.$style.button2)
        },
        computed: {
          dynamicClass() { 
              return this.$style[this.typeOfButton]
          }
        },
        methods: {
            showStyleObject() {
                console.log(this.$style)
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style module>
    .button {
        background: red;
    }

    .button2 {
        padding: 8px 10px;
    }

    .primary {
        padding: 8px 10px;
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .secondary {
        padding: 8px 15px;
        background: darkslategrey;
        color: aliceblue;
        border: none;
    }

    .default {
        background: aliceblue;
    }
</style>
```